# Why can't Windows 7 search FIND ANYTHING in my User Home folder or most other places?

Tags: windows-7, search

Here's my Search setup in Windows 7:

[image]

Here's the folder I want Windows to search:

[image]

Here's me telling it to search (what it searches for is immaterial. It NEVER finds ANYTHING:

[image]

It should have found at least the `NetBeansProjects` folder, but NOOOOOOOOO.

Another search, should have found several `docx` files as shown above:

[image]

Tell me why the Java program I wrote has no trouble finding anything i ask it to but Windows 7 Search finds nothing!!

[image]

Comment: Your C: is your Google Drive?

Comment: Is your Windows Search service running ? Have you tried rebuilding search index ?

Comment: I just noticed that Google Drive is shown as C:. That should not be what's happening. I've just noticed other drives with ... what are these--aliases? Like L: is listed as L: (V:). I just had to reformat drive C: ... Now I'm confused. But my Java program has no trouble finding stuff... I am now rebuilding the search indexes. I'll come back tomorrow as it is taking forever.